# Naming time series by a list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, time-series

So I have a list of countries in python

```
CountryList= ['Country A', 'Country B', ...]
```

And then a dictionary that maps each country to a key.

```
Countries = {'Country A' : "Key A", 'Country B' : "Key B", ...}
```

I want to make a loop using CountryList and Countries to store financial information (Using quandl) for each country to the country name.

ex. so if I type USA I should get all DJIA information given to my when I use Quandl.get()

My code doesn't work because it just assigns the data to CountryList instead of making a new variable Country A.

```
for i in range(0, len(CountryList)):
    CountryList[i] = Quandl.get(Countries[CountryList[i]], ...)
```

But how do I make this work?

Comment: That is **not** how names in Python work (see e.g. [this](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names)). Keep data out of your variable names. If you want to access a country by name, use a dictionary: instead of `USA` you just need `data['USA']`.

Comment: how would you recommend I store the data then? make another dictionary?